# Changing the line type in the ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a df:

```
head(hej3)

  Year          variable  N   Sum      Mean        sd   Variance Median Min  Max
1 1901     Delägare.män. 85 18089 212.81176 365.39168 133511.083  110.0   5 2771
2 1901 Delägare.kvinnor. 48  3509  73.10417  97.84209   9573.074   34.5   1  414
3 1902     Delägare.män. 92 19783 215.03261 363.63529 132230.625  111.5   2 2827
4 1902 Delägare.kvinnor. 53  3872  73.05660  94.12827   8860.131   40.0   1  408
5 1903     Delägare.män. 99 21123 213.36364 366.58411 134383.907  109.0   2 2994
6 1903 Delägare.kvinnor. 55  4201  76.38182  93.85006   8807.833   40.0   1  390
```

```
hej3 <- data.frame(
  Year = rep(
    c(
      1901L, 1902L, 1903L, 1904L, 1905L, 1906L, 1907L, 1908L, 1909L,
      1910L, 1911L, 1912L, 1915L, 1921L, 1924L, 1927L, 1930L
    ),
    each = 2L
  ),
  variable = factor(
    rep(c("Delägare.män.", "Delägare.kvinnor."), 17),
    levels = c("Delägare.män.", "Delägare.kvinnor.")
  ),
  N = c(
    85, 48, 92, 53, 99, 55, 112, 63, 116, 69, 126, 76, 130, 78, 130, 80, 129, 83,
    125, 81, 118, 77, 97, 72, 50, 41, 42, 34, 42, 33, 26, 20, 29, 29
  ),
  Sum = c(
    18089, 3509, 19783, 3872, 21123, 4201, 23686, 5087, 26751, 5652, 28198, 6493,
    31638, 6934, 32611, 7194, 36133, 7025, 30138, 6884, 26935, 6900, 20333, 8021,
    18929, 5619, 11157, 4332, 10778, 4437, 7974, 3416, 9270, 3793
  ),
  Mean = c(
    212.811764705882, 73.1041666666667, 215.032608695652, 73.0566037735849,
    213.363636363636, 76.3818181818182, 211.482142857143, 80.7460317460317,
    230.612068965517, 81.9130434782609, 223.793650793651, 85.4342105263158,
    243.369230769231, 88.8974358974359, 250.853846153846, 89.925,
    280.100775193798, 84.6385542168675, 241.104, 84.9876543209877,
    228.262711864407, 89.6103896103896, 209.618556701031, 111.402777777778,
    378.58, 137.048780487805, 265.642857142857, 127.411764705882,
    256.619047619048, 134.454545454545, 306.692307692308, 170.8, 319.655172413793,
    130.793103448276
  ),
  sd = c(
    365.391684625249, 97.8420871855394, 363.635291602196, 94.1282707255493,
    366.5841066326, 93.8500559223754, 373.650556559185, 106.929577104772,
    405.688052605677, 109.41727188241, 421.942750950132, 110.801123403007,
    462.951922738037, 115.87931358968, 502.602700547356, 117.741378786224,
    642.043293966629, 114.535815924939, 459.068496259615, 114.82317860815,
    360.246791665663, 119.967995276389, 293.702281347504, 224.695704072853,
    460.551137890511, 162.282154166672, 231.68690199813, 139.634830604701,
    226.30617641151, 143.124310240498, 343.058102277823, 181.389548819806,
    410.53721563181, 192.111645239046
  ),
  Variance = c(
    133511.083193277, 9573.0740248227, 132230.625298614, 8860.13134978229,
    134383.907235622, 8807.832996633, 139614.738416988, 11433.9344598054,
    164582.796026986, 11972.1393861893, 178035.685079365, 12276.8889473684,
    214324.482766846, 13428.0153180153, 252609.474597496, 13863.032278481,
    412219.591327519, 13118.4531295915, 210743.884258065, 13184.362345679,
    129777.750905403, 14392.3198906357, 86261.0300687285, 50488.159428795,
    212107.350612245, 26335.4975609756, 53678.8205574913, 19497.8859180036,
    51214.4854819977, 20484.5681818182, 117688.861538462, 32902.1684210526,
    168540.805418719, 36906.8842364532
  ),
  Median = c(
    110, 34.5, 111.5, 40, 109, 40, 112, 47, 109.5, 34, 111.5, 35, 120.5, 41.5,
    124.5, 46.5, 125, 44, 124, 44, 121, 44, 112, 42.5, 251, 85, 199.5, 93.5, 186,
    88, 206, 111, 185, 50
  ),
  Min = c(5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 19, 1, 19, 1, 19, 1, 49, 5, 0, 0),
  Max = c(
    2771, 414, 2827, 408, 2994, 390, 3196, 506, 3421, 524, 3680, 553, 3952, 570,
    4271, 581, 4585, 601, 3898, 602, 2603, 592, 1951, 1699, 2269, 675, 1151, 576,
    1122, 565, 1680, 652, 2086, 809
  )
)
```

I made a plot:

```
theplot<- ggplot(subset(hej3,variable=="Delägare.män."), aes(x = Year)) + 
  
geom_line(aes(y = Mean, color = "Medelvärde"), 
size = 1.5, linetype = 1, alpha = 1) + 
  
geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = Max, 
ymin = Min, fill = "Delägare Män Max/Min"), linetype = 3, 
alpha = 0.4) + 
  
geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = Mean+sd, ymin = Mean-sd, fill = "Mean +- sd"), 
colour = "grey50", linetype = 3, alpha = 0.8)+
  
#geom_line(aes(y = Sum, 
#color = "Sum Delägare Män"), size = 0.9, linetype = 1, alpha = 1) + 
  
geom_line(aes(y = N, 
                color = "Antal Kassor"), size = 0.9, linetype = 2, alpha = 1)+
  
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-500, 4800, by = 100), limits = c(-500, 4800), 
                   labels = seq(-500, 4800, by = 100))+ 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1901,1930,2))+
labs(title = "Manliga Delägare i Yrkeskassor") +
 
  scale_color_manual("Variabler", breaks = c("Antal Kassor","Medelvärde"),  
                     values = c("Antal Kassor" = "black", "Medelvärde" = "#6E6E6E")) + 
 scale_fill_manual(" Ribbons", breaks = c("Delägare Män Max/Min", "Mean +- sd"), 
                    values = c(`Delägare Män Max/Min` = "grey50", `Mean +- sd` = "#4E4E4E")) + 
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.position = "bottom", legend.key = element_blank(), 
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "gray30")) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth = 0.9, keyheight = 1))
```

[image]

I have `2 questions`:

1. How can I change the line type in the legend? I would like the `"Antal Kassor` variable in the legend to be dashed as in the picture (linetype=2).
2. How can I "zoom in" a part of y-axis? I would like to zoom in the area between -300 och 600 at the y-axis.

I know there are a lot of ggplot wizards here:) Best Regards!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To use your original data frame you should change to lines. In both calls to `geom_line()` put `linetype=` inside the `aes()` and set the type to variable name.

```
 + geom_line(aes(y = Mean, color = "Medelvärde",linetype = "Medelvärde"), 
            size = 1.5, alpha = 1)  
 + geom_line(aes(y = N, 
                color = "Antal Kassor",linetype="Antal Kassor"), size = 0.9, alpha = 1)
```

Then you should add `scale_linetype_manual()` with the same name as for `scale_colour_manual()` and there set line types you need.

```
+scale_linetype_manual("Variabler",values=c("Antal Kassor"=2,"Medelvärde"=1))
```

Also `guides()` should be adjusted for `linetype` and `colours` to better show lines in legend.

```
+ guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth = 1, keyheight = 1),
    linetype=guide_legend(keywidth = 3, keyheight = 1),
    colour=guide_legend(keywidth = 3, keyheight = 1))
```

[image]

Here is complete code used:

```
theplot<- ggplot(subset(hej3,variable=="Delägare.män."), aes(x = Year)) + 

  geom_line(aes(y = Mean, color = "Medelvärde",linetype = "Medelvärde"), 
            size = 1.5, alpha = 1) + 

  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = Max, 
                  ymin = Min, fill = "Delägare Män Max/Min"), linetype = 3, 
              alpha = 0.4) + 

  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = Mean+sd, ymin = Mean-sd, fill = "Mean +- sd"), 
              colour = "grey50", linetype = 3, alpha = 0.8)+

  #geom_line(aes(y = Sum, 
  #color = "Sum Delägare Män"), size = 0.9, linetype = 1, alpha = 1) + 

  geom_line(aes(y = N, 
                color = "Antal Kassor",linetype="Antal Kassor"), size = 0.9, alpha = 1)+

  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-500, 4800, by = 100), limits = c(-500, 4800), 
                     labels = seq(-500, 4800, by = 100))+ 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1901,1930,2))+
  labs(title = "Manliga Delägare i Yrkeskassor") +

  scale_color_manual("Variabler", breaks = c("Antal Kassor","Medelvärde"),  
                     values = c("Antal Kassor" = "black", "Medelvärde" = "#6E6E6E")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(" Ribbons", breaks = c("Delägare Män Max/Min", "Mean +- sd"), 
                    values = c(`Delägare Män Max/Min` = "grey50", `Mean +- sd` = "#4E4E4E")) + 
  scale_linetype_manual("Variabler",values=c("Antal Kassor"=2,"Medelvärde"=1))+
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.position = "bottom", legend.key = element_blank(), 
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "gray30")) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth = 1, keyheight = 1), linetype=guide_legend(keywidth = 3, keyheight = 1),
         colour=guide_legend(keywidth = 3, keyheight = 1)) +
     coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-300, 600))
```

Comment: @Didzis Eferts Brilliant!!:)

Answer (score 5):

1. Here you are want to change the linetype conditional on a variable. So, we create a new data set:

   ```
   R> library(reshape2)
   R> dd = melt(hej3, colnames(hej3)[c(1:2, 4, 6:10)])
   R> dd = dd[dd$variable=="Delägare.män.",c(1, 9:10)]
   R> head(dd, 4)
      Year variable value
   1  1901        N    85
   3  1902        N    92
   5  1903        N    99
   7  1904        N   112
   ```

   then we remove your two geom_line functions calls and replace with:

   ```
   + geom_line(data=dd, aes(x=Year, y = value, linetype=variable), 
             size = 1.5,  alpha = 1) +
   ```

   where the line type changes according to your variable.
2. To zoom into a region of you plot ([help page](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/coord_cartesian.html))

   ```
   + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-300, 600))
   ```

[image]

---

Full ggplot2 code for reference:

```
ggplot(subset(hej3,variable=="Delägare.män."), aes(x = Year)) + 
geom_line(data=dd, aes(x=Year, y = value, linetype=variable), 
          size = 1.5,  alpha = 1) + 
geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = Max, 
                ymin = Min, fill = "Delägare Män Max/Min"), linetype = 3, 
            alpha = 0.4) + 
geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = Mean+sd, ymin = Mean-sd, fill = "Mean +- sd"), 
            colour = "grey50", linetype = 3, alpha = 0.8)+
scale_color_manual("Variabler", breaks = c("Antal Kassor","Medelvärde"),  
                   values = c("Antal Kassor" = "black", "Medelvärde" = "#6E6E6E")) + 
scale_fill_manual(" Ribbons", breaks = c("Delägare Män Max/Min", "Mean +- sd"), 
                  values = c(`Delägare Män Max/Min` = "grey50", `Mean +- sd` = "#4E4E4E")) + 
theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.position = "bottom", legend.key = element_blank(), 
      legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "gray30")) + 
guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth = 0.9, keyheight = 1))    +
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-300, 600))
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer! But I actually modified the code from http://www.r-bloggers.com/ryan-peek-on-using-xts-and-ggplot-for-time-series-data/. So do you have a solution without melting the data?:)

Comment: (+1) very nice answer. I was struggling to find an answer! :)