# ggplot2 change line type

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been trying to plot two line graphs, one dashed and the other solid. I succeeded in doing so in the plot area, but the legend is problematic.

I looked at posts such as [Changing the line type in the ggplot legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875582/changing-the-line-type-in-the-ggplot-legend) , but I can't seem to fix the solution. Where have I gone wrong?

```
library(ggplot2)
year <- 2005:2015
variablea <- 1000:1010
variableb <- 1010:1020
df = data.frame(year, variablea, variableb)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = df$year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = df$variablea, colour="variablea", linetype="longdash")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = df$variableb, colour="variableb")) + 
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Value") + 
  scale_colour_manual("", breaks=c("variablea", "variableb")
                      , values=c("variablea"="red", "variableb"="blue")) + 
  scale_linetype_manual("", breaks=c("variablea", "variableb")
                      , values=c("longdash", "solid"))

p
```

[image]

Notice that both lines appear as solid in the legend.

Comment: reshape the data with `tidyr::gather` to put the data in one column, then it will just work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ggplot likes long data, so you can map linetype and color to a variable. For example,

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% gather(variable, value, -year) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value, colour = variable, linetype = variable)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Adjust color and linetype scales with the appropriate `scale_*_*` functions, if you like.

Comment: Great. How can I ensure that only integer years are displayed?

Comment: Use `scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2005, 2015, 5))`, passing in whatever sequence of breaks you want.