# ggplot2 geom_ribbon: decouple linetype aesthetic in legend from color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to display the **line type of the ribbon geom in the legend**. The issue is that the current representation of the line type int he legend is around a square colored with the line color. I hoped to be able to represent it just as a colored line. There are cases in which the line around the square is not easily identifiable.

The following plots are what I could get. Plot 1 displays the line type around the black squares, but I think it is a misleading representation as it might suggest that the black color is filling something. Plot 2 does not display it at all (I guess the color defaults to NA if not explicitly defined).

I think this is not an ideal behavior. In principle it should be desirable to display the line type as a (colored) line. In some situations it makes it tricky to tell the line type from the line color in the way the legend is represented.

Am I missing anything here?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(method = rep(c("b","a"), each = 3),
                   fill = rep(c("w","c"), each = 3),
                   x = c(1,3,6), ymin = 1:6, ymax = 3:8)
ggplot(data = data) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(x = x, ymin = ymin,
                ymax = ymax, fill = fill,
                linetype = method), alpha = 0.6, color = 'black')
```

[image]
***Plot 1:*** *Line type around colored square (looks as if it were representing the ribbon filling)*

```
ggplot(data = data) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(x = x, ymin = ymin,
                ymax = ymax, fill = fill,
                linetype = method), alpha = 0.6)
```

[image]
***Plot 2:*** *line type not displayed*

Comment: Personally I think this is reasonable default behavior - however there is some discussion here where you can find how to change the linetype legend manually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875582/changing-the-line-type-in-the-ggplot-legend

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. I think I hadn't explained myself properly, so I have edited the question. I hope it's better now. I don't have problems changing the ribbon linetype, I have problems with the representation of the ribbon linetype in the legend

Comment: Yes the link I sent you concerns the legends.