# Create colored regions below a line chart in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: line chart]
I'm working with the line chart above, which is generated by the code:

```r
ggplot(data=df) + geom_line(aes(x=date,y=germany,col="Germany")) +
  geom_line(aes(x=date,y=korea,col="Coreia do Sul"))  +  
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black","blue")) +
  ylab("Confirmed cases")
```

The first lines of the dataframe `df` are:

```r
  date             germany  korea
1 2020-01-22       0        1
2 2020-01-23       0        0
3 2020-01-24       0        1
4 2020-01-25       0        0
5 2020-01-26       0        1
6 2020-01-27       1        1
```

I would like to create colored regions below the curves, like this:
[image: line chart with regions]
Is it possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. The graph shown in the link has more than 1 value for each point on the x-axis. It also has the colour band set at a specific y-axis value, so there is a yellow horizontal band between 300 and 1000. Is that what you want - colour strips by y-axis values, with the Germany and Korea counts plotted as overlaid lines?

Comment: Exactly. My goal is to have a green region below 300, a yellow region between 300 and 1000 and red for values above 1000. Just like in the last image.

Comment: Does the geom_ribbon command in ggplot work for you? I've not used it myself. Here are two answers that reference the geom_ribbon option that might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277729/ggplot2-fill-color-behaviour-of-geom-ribbon and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49310317/ggplot2-geom-ribbon-decouple-linetype-aesthetic-in-legend-from-color. You'll need to change the colour options to get the ones you want, because the default aren't the same.

Comment: Knowing about the geom_ribbon() was exactly what i needed. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one basic approach.  Just as an illustrative proof of concept, let's take the two functions `y1(x) = sin(x) + 1` and `y2(x) = max(0, 8cos(x)exp(-.3x))` over [0, 5*pi] to represent some arbitrary data:

```
# libraries dplyr, tibble
df <- seq(0, 5*pi, by=.01) %>% 
    enframe(value="x") %>%
    mutate(y1=sin(x) + 1, y2=pmax(0, 8 * cos(x) * exp(-.3 * x) + 1));
```

Then we can use (for arbitrary breakpoints at 0.5 and 1.5):

```
df %>%
  mutate(ymax=pmax(y1, y2)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y1)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=pmin(ymax, 0),   ymax=pmin(ymax, 0.5)), fill='green') +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=pmin(ymax, 0.5), ymax=pmin(ymax, 1.5)), fill='yellow') +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=pmin(ymax, 1.5), ymax=pmin(ymax, max(ymax))), fill='red') +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(aes(y=y2), color='blue')
```

Yielding colored regions under the curves:

[image: Rplot output]